# Why when I get undefined when I console.log(createdAnimal)?

Tags: javascript, function

What I am trying to achieve in this code is to be able to console.log(createdAnimal) and then get the code to print out the objectAnimal with these parameters:

```
animalMaker('cat','flying',true);
```

It works when I invoke the animalMaker function, but I need it to work when I console.log(createdAnimal).

Thank you in advance!

Here is the code:

```
function animalMaker(inputType, inputSuperPower, inputCanFly){
  var objectAnimal = {
    'type': inputType,
    'inputSuperPower': inputSuperPower,
    'inputCanFly': inputCanFly,
    'createdBy': 'Scotty'
  };
  console.log(objectAnimal)
}

var createdAnimal = animalMaker('cat','flying',true); 

console.log(createdAnimal);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, your `animalMaker` function does not return anything, and when not returning a value, a function will by default return `undefined` in javascript.
So when setting a variable with the value from that the `animalMaker` function return, the value will be `undefined`.

For the `createdAnimal` variable to be set to the value of `objectAnimal`, you need to return it from the function. That you do by ending the `animalMaker` function with a return statement:

```
return objectAnimal;
```

Remember, code after a return statement in a function-clause will never be executed, `return` ends the function:

```
function example() {
    return true;
    console.log('This will never be printed');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the object from the function:

```
function animalMaker(inputType, inputSuperPower, inputCanFly){
  var objectAnimal = {
    'type': inputType,
    'inputSuperPower': inputSuperPower,
    'inputCanFly': inputCanFly,
    'createdBy': 'Scotty'
  };

  return objectAnimal;
}
```